# JavaScript, stringify, replacer - returning undefined vs. returning nothing

Tags: javascript, undefined, stringify

I am stringifying an object.

In one case my replacer function returns **undefined** for all properties (object is sealed):

```
str = JSON.stringify(o,function(k,v) {
    if(Object.isSealed(this)) {
        return undefined;
    } else {
        return v;
    }
});
```

in another, it returns nothing at all (both when the object is sealed and when not):

```
str = JSON.stringify(o,function(k,v) {
    if(Object.isSealed(this)) {
        return undefined;
    }
});
```

What I'm trying to understand is, why in the first scenario *str* is *"{}"*, but in the second *str* is *undefined*.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't provide an explicit `return`, the return value is `undefined`. Your second function *always* returns `undefined`, in other words. Because the function always returns `undefined`, there'll never be anything included in the JSON stringified result, so the overall effect is that you get `undefined`.

It's sort-of an anti-pattern to do this:

```
if (something) {
  return whatever;
}
else {
  return somethingElse;
}
```

Your first function would be more idiomatic as:

```
str = JSON.stringify(o,function(k,v) {
    return Object.isSealed(this) ? undefined : v;
});
```

*edit* — note that `JSON.stringify()` calls your replacer function *first* with an empty key, and "v" equal to <strike>`this`</strike> a new *wrapper* object containing the object to be stringified (and note that *that* object is *not* sealed).  That is, before checking each property of an object to be stringified, it asks the replacer function whether it should work on the object as a whole. Because your function always returns `undefined`, the stringify function thinks that there's absolutely nothing to be done. It can't return an empty object because your replacer function immediately told it "don't include this in the result".

Also note that the caller of your function cannot determine whether your function explicitly returned `undefined` or if it returned `undefined` because it didn't return anything, in case that's not clear. Those two cases look exactly the same to the caller.

Comment: Right. I get that, but even if nothing is returned, why isn't the resulting string still not an empty object as in the first case?

Comment: @R.V. hold on, I'll extend the answer.

Comment: RE: your edit. OK. But then why doesn't the first case return undefined, but instead returns "{}"?

Comment: @R.V. ah - I was wrong about the initial call - updating answer again.

Comment: @R.V. it's because the initial call to your replacer has `this` set to a dummy wrapper object, not your object.  That wrapper object is not sealed, so your function returns "v" (the sealed object). The wrapper is apparently made up by the JSON API to bootstrap the process.

Comment: haha OK, RE: your second edit, the calls are not the same to the caller. In the first case I get "{}" - an empty object. In the second I get undefined.

Comment: @R.V. yes, right. In your first example, you only return `undefined` when the object referenced by `this` is sealed. On the very first call, the value of `this` is **not** your sealed object, it's a different object made by the browser just for that initial call to the replacer function. Because that object is not sealed, your function returns "v", and the value of "v" is your sealed object. The first time you return `undefined` therefore is for the first property of your sealed object. The result is therefor an empty object.

Comment: so does it mean that in the second case the first value passed is not the wrapper object?

Comment: @R.V. in the second case, it **is** the wrapper object, but you **always** return `undefined`!  In the first case you only return `undefined` when `this` is a sealed object.  The two functions are different!

Answer (score 0):

The function:

```
function(k,v) {
    if(Object.isSealed(this)) {
        return undefined;
    }
};
```

Looks completely pointless to me.  It's phystically *not capable* of returning anything *but* undefined.

Your first function, however, will *either* return `undefined`, or the value that was passed in.

In JavaScript, the following functions would be considered identical as far as their return values:

```
function a()
{
   return undefined; // Provided undefined was not re-defined anywhere
}

function b()
{
   return;
}

function c()
{
}
```

Comment: It is pointless, I know. I'm trying to understand why the resulting string is not an empty object when the replacer returns no values?

Comment: Is `Object.isSealed(this)` true or false?

Answer (score 0):

Ideal case for using **return**:-
When the function is generating some value and you want to pass it back to the caller.

returning undefined is ***MEANINGLESS***.

If you want to return nothing-:
Just return null

```
if(Object.isSealed(this)) {
        return null;//or just  dont return anything!!!
    }
```

Comment: That is not true in the case of the `JSON.stringify()` function. The return value `undefined` definitely means something.  (Now it could be argued that a plain empty `return` statement would be more succinct, but again in this case the explicit `undefined` has meaning.)

Comment: @Pointy:i am not sure,What OP is exactly trying to do,but with the limited understanding that i have about javascript,I cant think of any  good reason why any one would like to return undefined..why not a null or a string if the function is not generating any value??just asking...

Comment: because the API he's using is explicitly written such that `undefined` means something. In that situation, `null` and `undefined` are not the same thing at all.  (Well, they're really not the same thing ever.)

Comment: accepted..i do understand the difference between null and undefined..but its difficult to digest the fact that some body needs to return undefined..

Comment: @MESSIAH The OP stumbled upon this discrepancy by accident and is trying to understand the cause. The code presented is not useful or functional in any way.

Comment: @MESSIAH well [here is the relevant documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_native_JSON#The_replacer_parameter).